# optimizer_search_depth in Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I have a problem in my Google Cloud SQL database. State of some queries stays "statistics" for long time.

```
+-------+------+-----------+------+---------+------+------------+--------------
| Id    | User | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State      | Info         
+-------+------+-----------+------+---------+------+------------+--------------
| 18533 | root | localhost | mydb | Execute | 2485 | statistics | SELECT * FROM...
| 18537 | root | localhost | mydb | Execute | 2424 | statistics | SELECT * FROM...
| 18539 | root | localhost | mydb | Execute | 2363 | statistics | SELECT * FROM...
| 18542 | root | localhost | mydb | Execute | 2304 | statistics | SELECT * FROM...
```

I read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797191/sql-query-stuck-in-statistics-state). And I want to change "optimizer_search_depth" setting, but I can't find this setting in Google developer console -> Cloud SQL.

Can Google Cloud SQL change this setting? If it can't, is there another way to avoid long statistics issue?

Comment: If you have spent 40 minutes on "statistics", I suspect something else is the real problem/solution.  Please show us all of one of those SELECTs, together with SHOW CREATE TABLE.

Comment: The only time I have seen optimizer_search_depth of use is in a key-value schema with lots of JOINs.  EAV is an awful schema.

Comment: I changed optimizer_search_depth to 0, but this does not take effect as you guessed. I have posted [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112244/query-stays-statistics-state-for-long-time-in-google-cloud-sql-mysql-5-5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We heard you :) I've sent out a change that will add optimizer_search_depth as a configurable flag for Cloud SQL for MySQL 5.5 and 5.6. It needs to go through some rounds of review, but should be available sometime early next week.

I hope this helps you with your long queries!

Chris, Cloud SQL team