# Query stays "statistics" state for long time in Google Cloud SQL (MySQL 5.5)

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

Some queries stays "statistics" state for long time in my Google Cloud SQL Database. (MySQL 5.5)

After [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875929/optimizer-search-depth-in-google-cloud-sql), I changed optimizer_search_depth to 0. But some queries still have long statistics time.

```
> select @@optimizer_search_depth;
+--------------------------+
| @@optimizer_search_depth |
+--------------------------+
|                        0 |
+--------------------------+

> show processlist;
+----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+------------+-----------------+
| Id | User | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State      | Info            |
+----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+------------+-----------------+
|  4 | root | localhost | mydb | Query   |   84 | statistics | SELECT * FROM ..|
```

Table and count is as below.

```
> describe mytable;
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field    | Type          | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| col1     | varchar(50)   | NO   | PRI | NULL                |                             |
| col2     | varchar(50)   | NO   | PRI | NULL                |                             |
| col3     | decimal(15,4) | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| col4     | decimal(15,4) | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| col5     | decimal(15,4) | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| col6     | decimal(15,4) | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| col7     | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| col8     | decimal(15,4) | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| col9     | decimal(15,4) | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| col10    | varchar(8)    | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| col11    | varchar(30)   | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| col12    | timestamp     | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                             |
| col13    | timestamp     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| col14    | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+

> select count(*) from mytable;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   852304 |
+----------+
```

Query is like this.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 
((col1 = 'FFP60003' AND col2 = '360' ) OR 
(col1 = 'FIU51001' AND col2 = '210' ) OR 
(col1 = 'FIU51003' AND col2 = '360' ) OR 
(col1 = 'FPC60001' AND col2 = '240' ) OR 
(col1 = 'SLU50006' AND col2 = '360' ) OR 
... (about 2000-3000 and/or) ...
(col1 = '89969' AND col2 = '270' ) ) AND col14 > 0
```

As shown above, query is very long. I think this is the cause of long statistics state, but my app needs this type of query.

How can I avoid long statistics issue?

**[Update]**

`SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%'` are as belows.

```
> show create table mytable\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: mytable
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `col1` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'col1',
  `col2` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'col2',
  `col3` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'col3',
  `col4` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'col4',
  `col5` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'col5',
  `col6` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'col6',
  `col7` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'col7',
  `col8` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'col8',
  `col9` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'col9',
  `col10` varchar(8) NOT NULL COMMENT 'col10',
  `col11` varchar(30) NOT NULL COMMENT 'col11',
  `col12` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'col12',
  `col13` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'col13',
  `col14` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'col14',
  PRIMARY KEY (`col1`,`col2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

 > SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';
+------------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name                | Value     |
+------------------------------+-----------+
| bulk_insert_buffer_size      | 8388608   |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances | 1         |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size      | 805306368 |
| innodb_change_buffering      | all       |
| innodb_log_buffer_size       | 8388608   |
| join_buffer_size             | 131072    |
| key_buffer_size              | 8388608   |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size      | 8388608   |
| net_buffer_length            | 16384     |
| preload_buffer_size          | 32768     |
| read_buffer_size             | 131072    |
| read_rnd_buffer_size         | 262144    |
| sort_buffer_size             | 2097152   |
| sql_buffer_result            | OFF       |
+------------------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: The `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` will probably say that it did a "table scan", as indicated by `ALL`.  That is because `OR` is hard to optimize.

Comment: If `col14` is selective enough, then `INDEX(col14)` would help.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable` -- we need to see the exact index(es), plus engine type.  (You can obscure or remove most of the columns if you need to.)  Also `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%'`.  How much RAM do you have?

Comment: I have updated my post. `col14` is not selective. More than 850,000 record have value 1.

Comment: Cloud SQL Instance type is "D2". This has 1GB RAM.

Answer (score 1):

In a 1GB server, do not have innodb_buffer_pool_size more than about 200M.  Setting it to 800M will cause swapping.  MySQL expects its caches to stay in RAM; when they get swapped to disk, performance suffers terribly.

Your table is probably to big to be cached entirely.  So, a "table scan" will blow out cache, making the cache useless and the query will run at disk speed.  Either find a way to avoid queries like that, or get more RAM.

Comment: I Changed Cloud SQL instance type "D8" that has 4GB RAM. This takes some effect, but still have 50secs statistics state. After I upgraded instance type to D8, innodb_buffer_pool_size becomes 3221225472. Google automatically sets this value, and does not allow change this value.

Comment: 3G/4G is tight; it does not leave much room for the OS, and for other buffers, caches, etc.  Are there metrics to see if the instance is "swapping"?

Comment: Was the Cloud service setting 800M on the 1G VM?  Was the 1G supposed to include the OS, etc?  If so, switch providers, they don't know what they are doing.